# Reloading JavaScript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to reload a JS file after a change occurs while the application is running on the server. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you explain better= This is not understandable

Comment: Please elaborate on why you'd want to do this. For example, if you need to bind functions to new DOM elements that were generated since the initial page load, reloading the file wouldn't be the best solution.

Comment: There is an asset pipeline. Assets are loaded into a pipeline. Assets are loaded into the pipeline when the server starts. I would like to reload an asset in the pipeline after the server has already started. I would like to reload an asset in the pipeline the page reloads. So there's an asset in the pipeline, a page reloads, I would like to reload the aforementioned asset.